# Java - KeyBinds stop working after holding down a key

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

*Update - I took my project from my MacBook and moved it to a windows computer (Same exact code) and the code works just as it is supposed to! Does anyone know why this would happen?

This is my first question here on Stack Overflow so I will try me best to do the correct formatting.

I am making a simple Pong program that needs a paddle to move up and down on key events (A & Z). The key events work perfect when I simply type a key but when I hold down a key for too long for some reason the key events stop working entirely, meaning that even the typing of the keys won't register anything anymore until I restart the program.

I have searched for the answer for over 2 hours with no avail. Every question that seems similar ends up with an answer of the focus being the problem and adding JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW inside the InputMap. However I have tried this and it does not help or fix my problem at all.

Here is my code:

```
public class ColorPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    public ColorPanel(Color backColor, int width, int height){

   //Non Relavent coding removed

    //Code for KeyBinding

    InputMap im = getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    ActionMap am = getActionMap();

    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(65, 0, false), "actionName");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(65, 0, true), "actionName");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, 0, true), "actionName");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, 0, false), "actionName");

    am.put("actionName", new AbstractAction("actionName") {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //System.out.println("---" + e.getActionCommand() + "---");
            if(e.getActionCommand().equals("a")){
                System.out.println("a!");
            }else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("z")){
                System.out.println("z!");
            }
          }
        });


}
```

Comment: Works fine for me using JDK8 on Windows 7. I Just used a single panel on a JFrame. `This is my first question here on Stack Overflow` - post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problems. We don't know if there is anything else in your program that could be causing the problem.

Comment: I looked into what you said and tried my project out on a windows device as I am using a mac. The problem went away!? Do you know any idea why this would happen?

Comment: I've never used a Mac so I'm not sure what the problem would be. However on Windows when you hold a key down you get events generated like "pressed, pressed, pressed, .....released". That is the "released" event is only generated once. On a Mac I believe you get: "pressed, released, pressed, released, pressed, released". That is for some reason the released event is continually generated. Maybe this is causing the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the macOS accent popup that usually appears when you hold down a key. For some reason this is confusing Java. See here: http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/apple/easy-mac-hacks-disable-the-pop-up-accent-window-when-typing-1305618