# Check if a Java version is greater than a certain iteration in Java?

Tags: java, version, apache-commons, apache-commons-lang3

I wish to check if a user's Java version is at least 1.8.0_171. I mean that specific iteration or higher, meaning 1.8.0_151, for instance, would not work.

I planned to originally use org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils' `isJavaVersionAtLeast(JavaVersion requiredVersion)` method, but it seems that you cannot specify the iteration number.

Based on this and Java's changing way of representing version numbers in Java (e.g. 1.8 then 9), what is the best way to check the Java version of the user in the Java program?

**Edit:**

This was marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103121/how-to-find-the-jvm-version-from-a-program); however, I think it is different in that it asks how to compare the java version with a certain version given the changes in format of how the java version is shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even with the versioning change, I think the solution is still as simple as using the following boolean expression:

```
"1.8.0_171".compareTo(System.getProperty("java.version")) <= 0
```

If the user's `java.version` property is any less than `1.8.0_171`, then the above expression returns false, and vice versa.  This works for using `"9"` or `"10"` in place of the `java.version` property as well.

Comment: This seems correct. I'll use this and make sure this doesn't change at all based on OS

Comment: I'm going under the assumption that `System.getProperty` is OS-independent; please let me know if there's some edge case that doesn't work.

Comment: What's about version "1.8.0_41" ? I think it won't work, because 41>171 (according to alphabetical order) ... :O